# For entourage $U_0\in\mathcal{U}$, is there a closed entourage $U_1\subseteq U_0$?

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal{U})$ be an uniform space. I know that for closed neighborhood $D$ of $\Delta_X$, there is no an entourage $U\in \mathcal{U}$ with $U\subseteq D$, in general.

Is it true for an entourage $U_0\in\mathcal{U}$, there is a closed entourage $U_1\in\mathcal{U}$ with $U_1\subseteq U_0$?

Please help me to know it.

Comment: did you try taking $V$ with $V^2\subseteq U$ ? Do you have more details for what you write you know, that in general there is no entourage for a a closed neighborhood?

Comment: @Mirko, in the following link, you can see an example that in general there is no entourage for a  closed neighborhood

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3063743/for-every-closed-neighborhood-delta-x-subset-d-is-there-an-entourage-u-wi?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known that in a uniform space, that if $V^3 \subseteq U$ then $\overline{V} \subseteq U$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can we say that $\overline{V}\in\mathcal{U}$?

Comment: Yes, if we take $V \in \mathcal{U}$, which we can. Larger sets will still be in the uniformity (it's one of the axioms).